# Spark + Kafka app, getting "CassandraCatalogException: Attempting to write to C* Table but missing primary key columns: [col1,col2,col3]"

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

**Run env**

```
kafka ----ReadStream----> local ----WriteStream----> cassandra \
```

source code place on local and kafka, local, writeStream is different IP \

Table columns are:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7
```

df.printSchema is

```
root
|-- key: binary (nullable = true)
|-- value: binary (nullable = true)
|-- topic: string (nullable = true)
|-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
|-- offset: long (nullable = true)
|-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)
```

Sorry, I try solve alone but can't find any solution.

**Run Code**

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,
com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.2.0,
com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:3.1.15
--conf com.datastax.spark:spark.cassandra.connectiohost{cassandraIP},
spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions test.py
```

Source code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Spark Bridge local to spark_master == Connect master
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("spark://{SparkMasterIP}:7077") \
    .appName("Spark_Streaming+kafka+cassandra") \
    .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', '{cassandraIP}') \
    .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', '9042') \
    .getOrCreate()

# Read Stream From {Topic} at BootStrap
df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "{KafkaIP}:9092") \
    .option('startingOffsets','earliest') \
    .option('failOnDataLoss','False') \
    .option("subscribe", "{Topic}") \
    .load() \

df.printSchema()

# write Stream at cassandra
ds = df.writeStream \
    .trigger(processingTime='15 seconds') \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
    .option("checkpointLocation","{checkpoint}") \
    .options(table='{table}',keyspace="{key}") \
    .outputMode('update') \
    .start()

ds.awaitTermination()
```

I get this error:

> com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalogException: Attempting to write to C* Table but missing
> primary key columns: [col1,col2,col3]
>
> at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraWriteBuilder.(CassandraWriteBuilder.scala:44)
> at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraTable.newWriteBuilder(CassandraTable.scala:69)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.createStreamingWrite(StreamExecution.scala:590)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(MicroBatchExecution.scala:140)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan(MicroBatchExecution.scala:59)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:295)
> at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
> at  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStr
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:209)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/test.py", line 33, in 
> ds.awaitTermination()
>
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 101, in awaitTe
>
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in
> File "/home/jeju/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
> pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: Attempting to write to C* Table but missing
> primary key columns: [col1,col2,col3]
> === Streaming Query ===
> Identifier: [id = d7da05f9-29a2-4597-a2c9-86a4ebfa65f2, runId = eea59c10-30fa-4939-8a30-03bd7c96b3f2]
> Current Committed Offsets: {}
> Current Available Offsets: {}

Comment: What is the output of  df.printSchema()? Data received from kafka may need to be parsed.

Comment: @ozlemg so..... kafka ---readStream---> parse ----> parseData --writeStream-->cassandra
is right??

Comment: Yes, the error happens because you're missing decoding of data in Kafka. When you read from Kafka, data is coming as binary blobs that needs to be parsed according to the format you encode the data

Comment: @AlexOtt thanks when i found spark stream your comment &Answer was helpful very thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says primary key columns: [col1,col2,col3] are missing. So df doesn't have these columns. You already have df.printSchema(). You can see it yourself that thats the case. df read from Kafka has a fixed schema and you can extract your data by parsing key and value columns. In my case data sent was in value column(if you need you can add key column as well) and json formatted. So i could read it by following code:

```
dfPerson = spark \
.readStream \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "x.x.x.x") \
.option("subscribe", TOPIC) \
.option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
.load()\
.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("data"))\
.select("data.*")
```

Hope it helps.